# can't get data out of response.body().string() in okhttp?

Tags: android, okhttp

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   String jsonData;
   Response response;
   JSONArray Jarray;
   private String TAG;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new                                                
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String token="a";
    RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("Token",token)
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://www.auffers.com/test/index.php")
            .post(body)
            .build();
    Response response = null;
    try {
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) try {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
    for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " +      responseHeaders.value(i));
    }

    try {
        System.out.println(response.body().string());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

gives me `{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }` but i am not able to get different elements like name, age, city out of it so that i can save them in my database. I have looked into many answers but not able to do this 
Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Where is your JSON parsing code?

Comment: @KNeerajLal i have updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
    String name = json.getString("name");
    String city = json.getString("city");
    int age = json.getInt("age");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `Integer age = json.getInt("age");` bro add this one instead of `String age = json.getInt("age");`

Comment: Thanks, just because of copy paste

Comment: No Problem Man :)

Comment: Either there is some other issue or json response might be different in that case

Comment: try out retrofit2

Comment: yeah i upvoted, just wondering why i got 3 down votes, was it such a lame question :)